# HTML5 video not playing properly in Firefox browser on OS X

Tags: python, html, firefox, ffmpeg

#### The issue:

I recently made a video that I would like to embed in my website as html5 video. I have the video in .mp4 and .ogv format. Here is a test page that I have set up with the video:

http://www.briancjenkins.com/video_test/

Here is the relevant html code that I used to embed the video:

```
<video width="75%" controls loop poster="US_Inflation_Unemployment_Monthly_BP_Filtered.png">
  <source src="US_Inflation_Unemployment_Monthly_BP_Filtered.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="US_Inflation_Unemployment_Monthly_BP_Filtered.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The video plays perfectly on Safari (iOS and OS X), Chrome (OS X), and Firefox (iOS).

However, the video *does not* play properly in Firefox on OS X. On both my desktop and laptop, when I play the video, the time bar moves, but there is no video. However, if I copy and paste the video URL into the Firefox address bar, the video plays fine. Here a the direct link to the .ogv-format video:

http://www.briancjenkins.com/video_test/US_Inflation_Unemployment_Monthly_BP_Filtered.ogv

I would like to know why the video is not playing in Firefox on OS X and how to fix the problem.

#### What I know about the issue:

I know that plenty of people have had trouble with html5 video and Firefox. And I also know from reading other questions that in some cases, the server is sending an incorrect mime type. I ran:

```
$ curl -I http://www.briancjenkins.com/video_test/US_Inflation_Unemployment_Monthly_BP_Filtered.ogv
```

and found that this does not seem to be the case here:

```
Server: GitHub.com
Content-Type: video/ogg
```

which isn't too surprising since Firefox *will* play the video hosted by Github, just not when its embedded in a webpage. Note that I also tried converting to .webm as an alternative to .ogv but that didn't solve the issue.

#### About the video

The video was created in Python and and Matplotlib. I used Matplotlib to save the video to .mp4 and then I used ffmpeg to convert the video to .ogv format. Here is the ffmpeg command I used:

```
$ ffmpeg -i US_Inflation_Unemployment_Monthly_BP_Filtered.mp4 -acodec libvorbis -ac 2 -ab 128k -ar 44100 -b:v 1800k  US_Inflation_Unemployment_Monthly_BP_Filtered.ogv
```

It's possible that I am not doing the conversion correctly, but I have tried several different variations on the conversion command. The video in question is hosted by Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** It seems that the issue has been resolved in the current version of Firefox.